# Using MySQL, I need to figure out how to take two data types (text and date) and output them in sentence form

Tags: mysql, string, function, date

Incorporating both text and date data types in a user-defined function is proving to be more difficult than I thought. Do I need 2 distinct declare statements? And in the 'RETURNS |DATATYPE| DETERMINISTIC keywords, which do I use (or do I include both)? I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework for me. Just point me in the right direction. Thanks!

I have browsed various mysql tutorials but none of them seem to have solutions or guides when it comes to a user entering mixed data types.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION in_sentence_form (u_name TEXT, b_date DATE)
RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE full_sentence TEXT;
SET full_sentence = (u_name," was born on ",b_date);
RETURN full_sentence;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This select statement:
select in_sentence_form("Jaron",2001-05-01);
results in a this error:
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '1995' for column 'b_date' at row

Comment: Never enclose string literals in double quotes! Always use single quotes, so `"Jaron"` should read `'Jaron'`, `" was born on "` `' was born on '`, etc.. Date literals are also enclosed in single quotes. What you have now, `2001-05-01`, is interpreted as an arithmetic operation and thus yields `1995`. And you might want to take a look at the `concat()` function, that could become useful in your function.

Comment: Thanks, sticky bit, everything you suggested worked. (Can't believe I forgot about how dates require quotes!) And my teacher would kill me if he knew I had overlooked the CONCAT function. (Guess I was tired last night.) Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: @stickybit - It looks like I get extra-credit if I format the date. I've tried SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b_date, ''%W %D %M %Y') but it looks like the SELECT is not allowed. I've also tried DECLARE and SET (I knew those wouldn't work but had to try). . . is it formatted outside of the BEGIN-END section maybe??? I'll keep working at it (ugh)

Comment: Hint: You can nest functions. (And actually directly return (scalar) expressions, i.e. other than the parameters, it's possible to write your function without any variables just returning a single expression (and ultimately replace the whole function by that expression, but I guess that's not what the exercise wants)).

Comment: Through trial and error, I believe I got what the teacher is asking for.  Here is the SET line in the function:

    SET full_sentence = CONCAT(u_name,' was born on ', DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%W'), ", the ", DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%D'), " day of ", DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%M'), ", ", DATE_FORMAT(b_date,'%Y'),".");

Whew!